# server side rendering for react, webpack, node project breaking because 'window' undefined

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, webpack, serverside-javascript

I get the following error when trying to do server-side rendering with components that reference window. For example when I include slick-carousel (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) I get the following error:

```
var Slick = window.Slick || {};
            ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I know its because window is not defined when trying to do SSR, but don't know what the best strategy is to avoid the error.

Comment: You could use `require` in componentDidMount, other than that you could stub window but I don't think that's a good idea. Or you could just write a slider in react or use one built for react ;)

Comment: Window is a browser attribute so you won't have access to it on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically components should not depend on DOM. Only, some hook methods such as `componentDidMount` can, where you use `.offsetHeight` and modify style or whatever. That's why `react` and `react-dom` packages are separated.

Instead of passing object by `window.XXX`, think about using decent dependency solution like `require`.